Rambam's endorsement of the Aleppo Codex
The wiki article on the Aleppo Codex (here) suggests that the Rambam endorsed its text: "[Rambam] described it as a text trusted by all Jewish scholars". However, following some of the references in the wiki it's unclear where he wrote this or what he specifically said about it.
Appreciate if someone can find a source. Thanks

https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/925430/jewish/Tefillin-Mezuzah-and-Sefer-Torah-Chapter-Eight.htm#v4

The source is Mishneh Torah, Sefer Ahava, Hilchos Tefilin, Mezuzah, and Sefer Torah, 8:4 (first paragraph):
וּלְפִי שֶׁרָאִיתִי שִׁבּוּשׁ גָּדוֹל בְּכָל הַסְּפָרִים שֶׁרָאִיתִי בִּדְבָרִים אֵלּוּ. וְכֵן בַּעֲלֵי הַמָּסֹרֶת שֶׁכּוֹתְבִין וּמְחַבְּרִין לְהוֹדִיעַ הַפְּתוּחוֹת וְהַסְּתוּמוֹת נֶחְלָקִים בִּדְבָרִים אֵלּוּ בְּמַחֲלֹקֶת הַסְּפָרִים שֶׁסּוֹמְכִין עֲלֵיהֶם. רָאִיתִי לִכְתֹּב הֵנָּה כָּל פָּרָשִׁיּוֹת הַתּוֹרָה הַסְּתוּמוֹת וְהַפְּתוּחוֹת וְצוּרַת הַשִּׁירוֹת כְּדֵי לְתַקֵּן עֲלֵיהֶם כָּל הַסְּפָרִים וּלְהַגִּיהַּ מֵהֶם. וְסֵפֶר שֶׁסָּמַכְנוּ עָלָיו בִּדְבָרִים אֵלּוּ הוּא הַסֵּפֶר הַיָּדוּעַ בְּמִצְרַיִם שֶׁהוּא כּוֹלֵל אַרְבָּעָה וְעֶשְׂרִים סְפָרִים שֶׁהָיָה בִּירוּשָׁלַיִם מִכַּמָּה שָׁנִים לְהַגִּיהַּ מִמֶּנּוּ הַסְּפָרִים וְעָלָיו הָיוּ הַכּל סוֹמְכִין לְפִי שֶׁהִגִּיהוֹ בֶּן אָשֵׁר וְדִקְדֵּק בּוֹ שָׁנִים הַרְבֵּה וְהִגִּיהוֹ פְּעָמִים רַבּוֹת כְּמוֹ שֶׁהֶעְתִּיקוּ וְעָלָיו סָמַכְתִּי בְּסֵפֶר הַתּוֹרָה שֶׁכָּתַבְתִּי כְּהִלְכָתוֹ:
Because I saw serious errors in these matters in all of the scrolls that I have seen, while authorities on the Massorah differ ... I deemed it fit to write here a list of the sections which are closed and which are open, and also the forms of the songs [of the Bible], so that all scrolls can be corrected from, and compared with, them. The book which I relied upon to check the scrolls is the well-known codex in Egypt which contains the twenty-four books [of the Bible] and that had been in Jerusalem for several years, and upon which all relied, because it was proofread by Ben Asher, who worked on it carefully for many years and examined it again whenever it was being copied. This codex was the text upon which I relied in the Scroll of the Torah that I myself wrote according to the halacha.

Assuming what we call the Aleppo Codex is in fact what Rambam was describing. Which is reasonable, if not 100% certain.

@Shalom Aleppo codex itself carried details of ownership and authorship. It has been a  carefully guarded manuscript for most of its history.

@Shalom Most of the critiques of the Codex-Rambam authenticity you may have heard are generally considered old and dealt with. The modern consensus is that it's the right book, mainly because no other period work comes even close to matching the Rambam's testimony of the sections therein, particularly when it comes to the layout of the songs which isn't meakeiv and had very high variance.

@DoubleAA fair enough. You've heard R' Shneur Lyman's story of Rabbi Cassuto's experiment? Cassuto though he could compare against his copy of the Yad ... oh well ...

@DoubleAA as you indicated, the probability that this codex is what he described far outweighs the probability that there was some other well-known work in the 12th Century Middle East that has since been totally lost to us.

@Shalom there is a publication of R. Breuer's notebook "Nusach haMikra b'Keter Yerushalaim" with documented variations in available texts as an addition to Keter Yerushalaim edition of Tanach. I think R. Breuer believed that the Tanach Scrolls from Taiman followed Rambam and they were careful to preserve the Keter Aram Tzova. I think that's how R. Breuer was reconstructing the missing pages.

@Shalom no it's not just the uniqueness of its fame, but uniqueness of its content. No other manuscript has 67 lines in Haazinu and there's no reason to think any other would.

@YDJ no he didn't reconstruct from the Yemenites but from other manuscripts similar to the Aleppo Codex (taking the majority reading and/or the reading supported by marginal notes). It just happened to match the Yemenites in most instances
